# org.json.JSONException: No value for results

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm trying to parse some data from my server using PHP into a ListView on Android Studio using JSONObject and JSONArrays and am getting an error in a for loop when trying to place the JSON into an object with the error being 'No value for results' despite outputting the JSON array earlier with it showing the data there.

Loop:

```
Log.d("json: ", result);

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

for (int i = 0; i<1; i++){//<jsonArray.length()-1

    JSONObject getObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject classObj = getObj.getJSONObject("results");

    Classes dailyClasses = new Classes();
    dailyClasses.setClass_id("" + classObj.getString("id"));
    dailyClasses.setClass_name("" + classObj.getString("name"));
    dailyClasses.setClass_room("" + classObj.getString("room"));
    dailyClasses.setClass_day("" + classObj.getString("day"));
    dailyClasses.setClass_time("" + classObj.getString("time"));

    classList.add(dailyClasses);
}
```

Error:

```
02-04 17:45:48.830 23024-23047/com.example.cameron.projectapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for results
```

That line being with 'results' being the name of my JSONArray:
 `JSONObject classObj = getObj.getJSONObject("results");`

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Sorry I forgot.

{"results":[{"id":"5","name":"Database Driven Websites","room":"HA LECTURE THEATRE","day":"Thursday","time":"09:00:00","course":"Software Engineering"},{"id":"6","name":"Database Driven Websites","room":"CM026","day":"Thursday","time":"10:00:00","course":"Software Engineering"},{"id":"7","name":"Enterprise Application Development","room":"CM011","day":"Thursday","time":"11:00:00","course":"Software Engineering"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already got the array now all you need is individual array, no need to get array again because its not there.

Change the `for` loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject classObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    Classes dailyClasses = new Classes();
    dailyClasses.setClass_id("" + classObj.getString("id"));
    dailyClasses.setClass_name("" + classObj.getString("name"));
    dailyClasses.setClass_room("" + classObj.getString("room"));
    dailyClasses.setClass_day("" + classObj.getString("day"));
    dailyClasses.setClass_time("" + classObj.getString("time"));

    classList.add(dailyClasses);
}
```

Comment: ah that fixed that.

However now i'm getting another error with: ArrayAdapter<Classes> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Classes>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_daily, classList);

Error: E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

Comment: Error: E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

Sorry, I clicked add comment before pasting it.

Comment: You need to use custom adapter because you have a custom object to display. Normal ArrayAdapter doesn't know what to display out of the object also the error means it needs a text view where it would show the data. I would **Highly** suggest you to use custom adapter here. You can control your list item view that way.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 for (int i = 0; i<1; i++){//<jsonArray.length()-1

            JSONObject classObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


            Classes dailyClasses = new Classes();
            dailyClasses.setClass_id("" + classObj.getString("id"));
            dailyClasses.setClass_name("" + classObj.getString("name"));
            dailyClasses.setClass_room("" + classObj.getString("room"));
            dailyClasses.setClass_day("" + classObj.getString("day"));
            dailyClasses.setClass_time("" + classObj.getString("time"));

            classList.add(dailyClasses);
        }
```